# How to set global variables in Javascript/HTML5 in Windows8 store app

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I want to use global variable in .js files.
For example,

when I read a file content in " a.js + a.html " and saved into a certain variable 'fileContent'

then I also want to use that 'fileContent' in " b.js + b.html ".

(also, when I change the 'fileContent' in "b.js + b.html", that should affect 'fileContent' in "a.js + a.html")

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: im not sure about windows 8 - but you could use stomething like localStorage or sessionStorage in javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the architecture for Windows 8 Applications is the single page model, where you don't navigate the browser, but merely load a fragment of HTML and insert it into the *current* document, this is very easy. I would, however, recommend using some typing, rather than just a "naked" global variable.

File A (globals.js):

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MyGlobals",  {
    variableA: null,
});
```

Include this at the top of default.html after the WinJS includes.

File B (b.js):

```
// your other code
...
MyGlobals.variableA = getValueFromSomewhere();
```

File C (b.html, or c.js):

```
// your other code
...
printSomethingAwesomeFromData(MyGlobals.variableA);
```

Comment: I have some questions. I actually did like that code. However, the value of variableA cannot be used in c.js   My goal is to make a WinJS.binding.list(); variable which can be shared in both b.js and c.js    My code is like the below:

Comment: [global.js] which is "included" in default.html --> WinJS.Namespace.define("MyGlobals", { varA:null, });

Comment: [b.js] MyGlobals.varA = new WinJS.binding.list();   and   MyGlobal.varA.push({title:varTitle, desc:varDesc});

Comment: [c.js] var theTitle=MyGlobal.varA.getAt(0).title;

Comment: here, when I debug c.js, MyGlobal.varA seems to be undefined. which means those variables in b.js and c.js are different even if the variable name, MyGlobal.varA is the same. @Dominic-Hopton

Comment: plus, I use 'navigator.js' for WinJS.Navigation.navigate

Comment: And your c.js is included after global.js?

Comment: yes, <script src=....global.js /> then <script src... c.js /> in default.html @Dominic Hopton

Comment: I've figured out what the problem was. Actually, the method for sharing variables was correct as you wrote above. I've made a mistake in other part of grammar that I pushed data into the binding.list() in Windows.Storage.PathIO.readTextAsync(dList.getAt(i).filepath).done(function (fileContent)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use App Settings:

```
var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
var localSettings = applicationData.localSettings;
var composite = new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
composite["intVal"] = 1;
composite["strVal"] = "string";

localSettings.values["exampleCompositeSetting"] = composite;
```

Here You can find more information: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465118%28v=win.10%29.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: `localSettings`? What's that?

Comment: I forgot add code. Now will be correct. Look to the link to get more information.

Comment: `applicationData`? I think you forgot `var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily define a variable and can use it as a global variable,for example

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("MyGlobals", {i: 0,k:5    })
```

For checking you can add an event listener like

```
div1.addEventListener('click', divClickEvent);

function divClickEvent() {
        MyGlobals.i++;
        MyGlobals.k++;
        console.log("ValueOf_i____" + MyGlobals.i);
        console.log("ValueOf_k____" + MyGlobals.k);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage.
In A:

```
localStorage.setItem('fileContent', 'value;');
```

In B:

```
var fileContent = localStorage.getItem('fileContent');
```

Or just access the `localStorage` like any other object:

```
localStorage.fileContent = "value";
```

However, keep in mind that the `localStorage` converts all values to strings, this includes objects and array. To set / get those, you'll need to use `JSON.stringify` and JSON.parse, respectively:

```
localStorage.setItem('fileContent', JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]));
var fileContent = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fileContent'));
```

Comment: thank you for the solution! but is there any method to use a defined variable? I mean that 'fileContent' variable which is defined in C.js and use that variable in a.js and b.js ?

Comment: @klados: Only if you want to use the variables on the same `.html` page. Otherwise, you'll have to rely on `localStorage` or cookies.