# What is the Windows 8 Application equivalent of "window."?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

When developing Windows 8 apps in JavaScript and HTML, what is the equivalent global variable for what would traditionally be `window.`

From a method inside an object on one page I need to access a method inside an object that is stored in a separate JS file. The object is called `searchAll` and the method is '_clearInput'. So for example I want to call `window.searchAll.clearInput`. The `searchAll' object is wrapped in an anonymous function.

How do I do this? Or is this the wrong way of approaching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a global, then just treat it as such:

```
searchAll.xxx()
```

Just don't mask it in a narrower scope with `var searchAll` or `function (searchAll) { }`

Comment: The object in the separate page is inside an anonymous function, I have tried accessing as you indicated previously but I get a "Cannot Be Found" style error.

Comment: If it is defined as a global, then being in a separate script file shouldn't be a barrier — http://jsbin.com/ineqaj/1/edit — if it is local to the function (e.g. with `var`) then it won't be exposed via the `window` equivalent anyway.

Comment: It is exposed with `var` (I am running in strict mode), is the only way to make it available then to create a name namespace and expose it that way?

Comment: Generally you can just return it from the anonymous function. var global = function () { /* ... */ return foo; }();

Comment: That worked, also there is a similar useful question that I didn't originally see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159022/how-to-set-global-variables-in-javascript-html5-in-windows8-store-app