# Passing variables values to another in a different namespace (Windows Store App, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Good day.

I need to find a way to pass a variable from a self executing anonymous function to another self executing anonymous function.

namely...

```
(function(){
"use strict";
//some code
//more code
})();
```

I am quite new to Javascript and Windows store apps, so it's quite vague for me if it really is possible(but being placed in a self executing anonymous function feels like it is impossible in the first place)

Is there a way to pass it to another page? I am using the Navigation template. Or if possible, can anybody show me how to declare and reuse variables in a global namespace? I don't know where to put the variables so I can't figure out if it is again, possible.

Thank you in advance.

---

My question was a duplicate of this one
[How to set global variables in Javascript/HTML5 in Windows8 store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159022/how-to-set-global-variables-in-javascript-html5-in-windows8-store-app)

I did not find the aforementioned question because I am searching for different keywords, and forgot to mention the global namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will check the link you just gave.

Comment: Excuse me edhedges, I think I already solved my problem. :) Thank you very much! Sorry for the misleading title of my post. :)

Comment: Well if it's different than the one I posted as a possible duplicate you should answer your own question or updated your question to reflect what you did.